# Collapse All Dojo Accordion Panes

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have the following XPage:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:djAccordionContainer id="djAccordionContainer1">
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane1"> 1 </xe:djAccordionPane>
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane2"> 2 </xe:djAccordionPane>
    </xe:djAccordionContainer>
</xp:view>`

When the page loads, `djAccordionPane1` opens automatically and displays "1". Is there a way to have the accordion collapse all panes on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion Panes render by dojo component. If you look into example http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html there is no "all collapsed" state.

You can workaround it by inserting "Info" panel at the top.

---

Panel 1: Info (expanded by default)

Some info message, like "Click the Content header to see what we got."

---

Panel 2: Content 1

---

Panel 3: Content 2

---

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean when you say: "...first, thin, default open "Info" panel."